# How do I extract all the words start with a vowel and length equal with n (in JAVA)?

Tags: java, string, j#

How do I extract words from a sentence where the word length=3 (or another number input by user) and also start with vowel?

```
public class LAB1 {

  public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException

  { 
    BufferedReader br=new BufferedReader (new InputStreamReader(System.in));

        System.out.print("Introduceți textul: ");
        String s=br.readLine();

        s = s+" ";

        int l=s.length();
        int pos=0;

        char ch1, ch2;
        String w;

        for(int i=0; i<l; i++)
        {
            ch1 = s.charAt(i);
            if(ch1 == ' ')
            {
                w = s.substring(pos,i); // extracting words one by one
                ch2 = w.charAt(0);

                if(ch2=='A' || ch2=='E' || ch2=='I' || ch2=='O' || ch2=='U' ||
                ch2=='a' || ch2=='e' || ch2=='i' || ch2=='o' || ch2=='u')
                {
                    System.out.println(w);
                }
                pos = i+1;
            }
        }
    }
}
```

run:
Introduceți textul: Sprin is Beautiful for Ana
is
Ana
СБОРКА УСПЕШНО ЗАВЕРШЕНА (общее время: 33 секунды)

Comment: I dont get what you're asking can you please explain yourself?

Comment: I think this would be easier to use `s.split("[\\s]+")` to split into the words. You then have a `String[]` you can process. It isn't clear that the AEIOU/aeiou is sufficient, as many languages have accents, etc. So you need to specify exactly what constitutes a vowel.

Comment: I need extract words which begins with vowels and length (n), I do not know how to print these words, because I've only selected words that start with vowels, but not with the specific length

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I agree that Regular Expressions could help, so one could do:

```
if (word.matches("(?i)^[aeiou].{2}")) { ... }
```

Where the "2" is adjusted to match the desired length - 1, and the "aeiou" could be expanded to support additional vowels.

However, such an approach is also fairly advanced. For a more basic approach, I'd consider splitting the issue into two different methods, and using a `switch` rather than a complicated `if` statement with a lot of `||` clauses.

```
public static void main(String[] args)
{
    // you can gather these entries from a Scanner, or whatever
    final String inp = "Spring is Amazingly Beautiful for Ana";
    final int len = 3;


    String[] words = extractWords(inp);
    for (String word : words) {
        if (correctLength(word, len) && startsWithVowel(word)) {
            System.out.println(word);
        }
    }
}

public static String[] extractWords(final String sentence)
{
    return sentence.split("[\\s]+");
}

public static boolean correctLength(String word, int expLen)
{
    return word.length() == expLen;
}

public static boolean startsWithVowel(final String word)
{
    if (word == null || word.isBlank()) {
        return false;
    }

    boolean startsWith = false;



    // really need to develop a comprehensive approach to what is a vowel
    // could use regular expressions,
    //
    // return word.matches("(?i)^[aeiou].*$");
    //
    // but it is slightly easier if 
    // just use a known set since there are more than aeiou in the world
    // also, we will set to lower case, so can use smaller set
    switch (word.toLowerCase().charAt(0)) {
    case 'a':
    case 'e':
    case 'i':
    case 'o':
    case 'u':
        startsWith = true;
        break;

    default:
        break;
    }

    return startsWith;
}
```

This approach separates the questions of the word length and the word start into separate methods (also supports easier testing), and uses the `.split()` to get the words.

Answer (score 2):

Take a look at Regex (regular expressions). They are designed for exactly this kind of problems and can be used in Java natively.

Some tutorial: https://www.vogella.com/tutorials/JavaRegularExpressions/article.html

For testing you regex, this is a handy site https://regexr.com/